# Gradle is completed destroy

Tags: android, gradle, google-play

I developed an android app in 2016. Then some gradle files has been deleted accidentally.
Now i want to update and upload my application on Google play. But old source code was not accepting phone to connect while debugging and even not building.

- I already have release signature key
- package name.
- All source code without gradle part.

Can I create another fresh app in android studio with same **package name** and **source code**.
New created debug application will work on every phone I know but when I signed it with my previous **release key** and upload it in **Google play** will it be accepted or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the package name and signing certificate are the same you can build an update for your APK however you want.

Answer (score 0):

For Android apps on Google playstore, package name is considered as your app's identity. Application will be considered as new application only if you change the package name.

Changing only the Keystore will also obstruct the ability to update app on play store and only way to recover would be to create app with new package name.

In your case if you maintain same package name and use same Keystore, there shouldn't be an issue to upload a new release. Since upload on Google Play store doesn't care about the environment used to build the apk.